# How do I keep a body unrendered in Libgdx Box2d?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I couldn't find the answer anywhere and I am starting to doubt if that's possible. How can I keep a body in LIbgdx "Invisble"? So that it will keep interacting with everything and act like a regular body but just won't be rendered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own [Box2dDebugRenderer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Box2DDebugRenderer.html) and override `renderBody` method.

```
class MyBox2dRenderer extends Box2DDebugRenderer {

    private ArrayList<Body> notRenderingBodies; // array of vodies that you dont want to render


    public MyBox2dRenderer(ArrayList<Body> notRenderingBodies) { 
        super();

        this.notRenderingBodies = notRenderingBodies; 
    }

    @Override
    protected void renderBody(Body body) {
        for (Body b : notRenderingBodies) { // loop through all bodies in array
            if (b == body){ // if given body equals by reference to one from list than return 
                return;
            }
        }
        super.renderBody(body);
    }

    public ArrayList<Body> getNotDenderingBodies() {
        return notRenderingBodies;   
    }

    public void setNotDenderingBodies(ArrayList<Body> notDenderingBodies) {
        this.notRenderingBodies = notDenderingBodies;
    }
}
```